# Check and Count User Purchases

Tags: c#, uwp

Hi I am developing UWP Microsfot Store App;
I need check and count user purchases in my add-ons.

Example I purchased 6(4xgold+2xsilver) products in my add-ons
I used this but  just get 2 products (gold-silver)

```
string[] productKinds = { "Consumable", "UnmanagedConsumable" };
var license = await _storeContext.GetUserCollectionAsync(productKinds);
```

And I tried this code but it returns null

```
appLicense = await context.GetAppLicenseAsync();
*.appLicese.AddOnLicenses
```

How I can get all user's purchases history ?

Edit : Min Target is Build 10240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer :

```
 private async void CheckBanner()
        {
            try
            {
                string[] productKinds = { "Consumable", "UnmanagedConsumable" };
                StatusBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                var userPurchases = await _storeContext.GetUserCollectionAsync(productKinds);
                StatusBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                foreach (var item in userPurchases.Products)
                {
                    var product = item.Value;
                    TextBlock count = GetProductQuatity(product.ExtendedJsonData)
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                //
            }

        }

        private string GetProductQuatity(string jsonData)
        {

            try
            {
                var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
                return obj["DisplaySkuAvailabilities"][0]["Sku"]["CollectionData"]["quantity"].ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                return "1";
            }
        }
```